# Restore single database from mysqldump to another database

Tags: mysql, database-restore

I have a mysqldump file that was created on our production server with the all-databases option.

Let's say the dump contains

- db1
- db2
- db3

I know I can restore just a single database with

```
mysql -D db3 -o < backup.sql
```

But I want to restore only `db3` to my dev machine but into another database, lets say `db3_production` since there is already a `db3` on my dev machine which I want to keep.

How can I do this? The file is to large to modify with a text editor.

Answer (score 2):

Get another text editor. Or filter your backup file through a program like `sed` before it gets into mysql, like in

```
cat backup.sql | sed "s/`db3`/`db4`/g" | mysql -D db4 -o
```

Comment: that would be a terrible idea, since the real dbname is not `db3` but our company name and the match count of the regex would be huge ;-)

Comment: That's why it is in apostrophes. Change the expression to \`db3\`.\` to make it even more specific.